# How do I configure Django URLS to work with all react-router paths

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use Django Python with React Javascript to create a web application. At first, my Django URLS would load my react-router-dom pages as 404, but after some researching I found that I could use `url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', views.index)` to load all of my "first level" pages. ex: `index/settings`. But this url map didn't work for my "second level" pages. ex: `index/settings/about`. I can't for the life of me figure out how load my second level pages, or re-engineer the previous solution to work for this. I would appreciate any insight on how to solve this issue, and perhaps these types of problems in general when it comes to URLS, because I am a relatively new programmer and I have LOTS to learn. Thanks!

EDIT: `r'^(?:.*)/?$'` isn't working for all of my url mappings so far. I believe that this is part of my main issue. I also deleted the extra url mapping in order to keep my code dry.

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from backend import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('backend.urls')),
    url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', views.index),

]
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import LoginIndex from './login_index';
import Settings from './settings';
import About from './about';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route  path="/login_index" component={LoginIndex} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route  path="/settings/about" component={About} />
        </div>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root', 'login_index', 'settings'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: You regular expression catches everything. You need something less greedy.

Comment: @Klaus D. I don't really understand what you mean by that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The regular expression `^(?:.*)/?$` matches on everything. It is equivalent to `^.*$`.

Comment: @Klaus D. Actually, my problem is that it isn't. I tried using this for urls such as `/settings` and it worked. But for `/settings/about` , `^(?:.*)/?$` gave me a 404. Any help on why that isn't working or what I should do?